# How to display perl script result in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, perl

I have read this link about how to execute a perl script from webpage.

[Best way to execute perl script from webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619590/best-way-to-execute-perl-script-from-webpage)

But now the situation is, I have a script that will run more than 30 seconds. And it would display a dynamic result in command prompt. I use what said in that link and only returns blank.

How can I display the result in webpage? It will be fine if only display the final result at the end of the perl script process. If it could display dynamically, it will be much more better.

I'm a newbie in web programming. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying it never displays anything, or it displays too slowly? If the the latter, simbabque has answered your question. If the former, find your apache access/error logs, do a request, and attach the relevant lines to your posting. Also, a blank page with no error can be simply due to bad HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is timing out. If your Perl script is printing something during the processing time and it is not showing up, start by putting `$|++` at the top, somewhere below `use CGI`. It will tell Perl to disable output buffering and start sending stuff as it gets printed. This is documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html).

If that doesn't help, try sending something as soon as you know that your program will succeed. Send the headers first, for example.

Usually Apache has a timeout value of 300 seconds. It might be in your case this was changed to a lower value. Contact your system admin or check yourself.